# wpf-CanResizeWithGrip option does not consider the minwidth and minheight properties

Tags: wpf, window, css, resize-crop

I have a little problem, when I resize the window with the grip, the window can be smaller then the minimum size parameters.

I tried this:

```
    private void wndMain_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check there is no Deviation in the height
        if (e.NewSize.Height < this.MinHeight)
        {
            this.Height = this.MinHeight;
        }

        // Check there is no Deviation in the width
        if (e.NewSize.Width < this.MinWidth)
        {
            this.Width = this.MinWidth;
        }
    }
```

But it looks terrible, Because the changing is haapened and resize again and again...

there is an option to cancel the resize into the sizechanged event?
thanks!